# mongoose express counter does not increment, scope problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, scope

the returned counter value is always 0. Why? How can I solve this problem?
In messages.findOne there the correct counter value. In conversation.forEach the counter value is always null.

```js
router.get('/isNewMessages', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = { usernames: req.user.username }
    Conversation.find(query, (err, conversations) => {
      var counterNewMessages = 0
      conversations.forEach(conversation => {
        console.log(counterNewMessages) // Here is always 0
        Messages.findOne({ _id: conversation.messages }, (err, messages) => {
          counterNewMessages += messages.messages.filter(message => !message.isRead && message.receiver === req.user.username).length
          console.log(counterNewMessages) // Here is value is correct
        })
      })
      res.status(201).send({ counterNewMessages })
    })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

Solution (Explanation in accepted answer):

```js
router.get('/isNewMessages', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = { usernames: req.user.username }
    Conversation.find(query, async (err, conversations) => {
      let counterNewMessages = 0
      for (const conversation of conversations) {
        await Messages.findOne({ _id: conversation.messages }, (err, messages) => {
          counterNewMessages += messages.messages.filter(message => !message.isRead && message.receiver === req.user.username).length
        })
      }
      res.status(201).send({ counterNewMessages })
    })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

Comment: Good job using the fancy new stuff with `async`/`await`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are incrementing within an async function. Therefore, `res.send` is happening before the call to `findOne` has actually returned a value; before the incrementing happens.

Comment: There are several ways you could solve this problem. You could write more efficient mongo queries for one. However, a simpler and more important concept for you to grasp is how to [use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: thank you. I will try it. I you know what is the best method then tell me...

Comment: You should certainly look into promises as they are a very fundamental part of Javascript development.

Comment: problem was it didnt know how to deal with forEach loop

Comment: `Promise.all` with maybe `.map` instead of `.forEach` would one way to handle collections of data.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue before and here is how I fixed it.

```
            const roomPromises = [];
            tourPackagesParams.roomPax.forEach(room => {
              if (
                <conditional statement>
              ) {
                roomPromises.push(fetchHotelRoomByRoomId(room.roomId));
              } else {
                roomPromises.push(Promise.resolve(null));
              }
            });

            const roomUpgrades = [];
            Promise.all([...roomPromises]).then(response => {
```

Comment: sorry @TobiasK my bad I overlooked that you were making another db call inside the loop. I updated my answer.